# Numpy: vector of indices and value

Tags: python, numpy

I guess I'm having a slow day and can't figure this one out. I have an m x n numpy array and want to convert it to a vector where each element is a 3 dimensional vector containing the row number, column number and value of all the elements in the array.

For example, given an numpy array, a, the first element in the vector would be: [1, 1, a[1, 1]] then the next would be [1, 2, a[1, 2]] etc.

Comment: Do you want to work with `m x n` arrays or with `n x 2` arrays?

Comment: @Bakuriu I would like it to scale to all sizes please.

Comment: In Python and numpy indexing starts at `0`.  So the first element would be `[0, 0, a[0,0]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence produces a (3, n*m) array with the indices and values

```
In [786]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [787]: X=np.vstack([np.indices(A.shape),A[None,...]]).reshape(3,-1)
In [788]: X.shape
Out[788]: (3, 12)
In [789]: X
Out[789]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

It can be transposed to make each 'row' represent an element:

```
In [793]: X.T[0,:]
Out[793]: array([0, 0, 0])
In [794]: X.T[10,:]
Out[794]: array([ 2,  2, 10])
```

It could also be cast into a structured array with length `(n*m,)`, and `dtype('i4,i4,i4')`.  This example is a bit messy, but it does job:

```
In [796]: dt=np.dtype('i4,i4,i4')
In [806]: X1=np.zeros(X.shape[1],dtype=dt)
In [809]: X1['f0']=X[0]
In [810]: X1['f1']=X[1]
In [811]: X1['f2']=X[2]
# or more compactly: for i,n in enumerate(X1.dtype.names): X1[n] = X[i,:]
In [812]: X1
Out[812]: 
array([(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 3, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 5),
       (1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 7), (2, 0, 8), (2, 1, 9), (2, 2, 10), (2, 3, 11)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
In [813]: X1[10]
Out[813]: (2, 2, 10)   # note, this a tuple
In [814]: X1['f2']
Out[814]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Lets say the original matrix is floats, and we want to preserve that type in the new array.  We could do that by skipping the `vstack` step:

```
In [833]: A = np.arange(12,dtype=float).reshape(3,4)
In [834]: X = np.indices(A.shape).reshape(2,-1)
...
In [848]: dt=np.dtype([('row',int), ('col',int), ('value',float)])
In [850]: X1 = np.zeros(X.shape[1], dtype=dt)
In [851]: X1['row']=X[0,:]
In [852]: X1['col']=X[1,:]
In [853]: X1['value']=A.flatten()
In [854]: X1
Out[854]: 
array([(0, 0, 0.0), (0, 1, 1.0), (0, 2, 2.0), (0, 3, 3.0), (1, 0, 4.0),
       (1, 1, 5.0), (1, 2, 6.0), (1, 3, 7.0), (2, 0, 8.0), (2, 1, 9.0),
       (2, 2, 10.0), (2, 3, 11.0)], 
      dtype=[('row', '<i4'), ('col', '<i4'), ('value', '<f8')])
In [855]: X1[10]
Out[855]: (2, 2, 10.0)
```

`X1[10]` is a `0D` array with dtype `dt`, and shape `()`, which prints as a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work:

```
n = 10
m = 5

data = np.random.randn(n, m)
grid = np.indices(data.shape)
r = np.array([grid[0], grid[1], data])
result = np.array(zip(*r.T))
```

There are probably more efficient ways to do this though.  See: [`numpy.indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html)

Comment: I needed it to be a vector of triples, your result is still an mxn array. I guess I just reshape the result?

Comment: Yes, I think you want `result = r.T.reshape(-1, 3)`

Comment: Do you want a 2d array, or a 1d array with tuple (dtype) elements?